# Is the discrete uniformity the only complete uniformity on the discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces, uniform-spaces

Here's a simple statement about uniformities that seems like it has to be true but which I can't quite seem to prove at the moment.  Say $X$ is a uniform space, and suppose 1. that $X$ is complete and that 2. considered as a topological space, $X$ is discrete.  Does $X$ have to be discrete as a uniform space?

Thank you all!

Edit: As per Mike F's answer, the statement is actually false.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space I think this Wikipedia article answers your question.

Comment: No, it does not.  It says nothing on the subject.  Its only remark on the subject of completeness is that the discrete uniformity is complete, which is obvious.  I'm asking about a sort of converse.

Comment: The discrete uniformity is of course the so-called fine uniformity for the discrete space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A metric space is:

- **topologically discrete** if, for all $x$, there exists $\epsilon_x > 0$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon_x$ implies $x=y$. Equivalently, there is no accumulation point in the space.
- **uniformly discrete** if there exists a global $\epsilon > 0$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ implies $x=y$. Turning this around, a metric space is **not** uniformly discrete if and only if the distance function takes on arbitrarily small positive values.

We want a metric space which is (1) complete, (2) topologically discrete, (3) not uniformly discrete. Let's try to achieve this with a subspace $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, with the standard metric structure. Let $A$ denote the set of accumulation points of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

- $X$ is complete if and only if it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $A \subseteq X$.
- $X$ is topologically discrete if and only if has no accumulation point in $X$, i.e. $A \cap X = \varnothing$.
- Combining the above, $X$ is complete and topologically discrete if and only if $A = \varnothing$.

So our goal is:

> Find a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which has no accumulation points in $\mathbb{R}$ and arbitrarily small positive distances between points.

Now that we know what we're looking for, it's not hard to think of examples. Here's one possiblity.

> Take $X = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ n + \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, in the standard absolute value metric. Then $X$ is a complete metric space which is topologically discrete but not uniformly discrete.

Comment: Your $Y$ is not complete; $(1/n)$ is a Cauchy sequence but doesn't converge.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks, I didn't actually see that requirement in the question. Made a small change, should be OK now.

Comment: Yes, it looks good now.

Comment: Oh, huh, so the statement is false.  Interesting, thanks!  (Note: You might want to remove the bit about $X$, as only $Y$ is relevant, and I was a bit confused trying to figure out how $X$ fit in.)

Comment: (Also, I should let this serve as a reminder to me to why one should also try to disprove statements one is trying to prove... I completely forgot to even try to here...)

Comment: @HarryAltman: That happens to me all the time! One way or another, I come to believe some false thing is true, and that belief seems to be  enough of a psychological barrier to stop me from noticing easy counterexamples.

Comment: @HarryAltman: I rewrote the answer. My reason for originally including a space $X$ and a space $Y$ was to highlight what property of discrete uniform spaces was not held by $Y$. But, I agree that it was confusing.